# oci_connect warning when connecting to oracle Database with php

Tags: php, oracle

I have 2 days now trying to connect to a remote oracle database installed in a machine running with windows 7.

From PHP server side I installed wampserver and oracle instant client 11.2 and I enabled oci8 php extension, I have also added instant client folder to my path variable.
From database side I have added TNS_ADMIN and ORACLE_HOME to path variable.

This is my php script:

```
    $db= "(DESCRIPTION =
              (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.43)(PORT = 1521))
              (CONNECT_DATA =
              (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                (SERVICE_NAME = hasdrubal)
              )
           )";
    $conn = oci_connect('SYSTEM', 'pass', $db);
    if (!$conn)
    {
       $e = oci_error();
      trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else
    {
       die("connected");
    }
```

I always get error

> oci_connect ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

the string is the same in the tsnames.ora and the listener is running. I checked that in services.msc.

Can you help me please?

Comment: So you can connect with sqlplus?

Comment: yes i can connect with sqlplus

Comment: The action for this error (as the documentation pointed): `Ensure that the supplied destination address matches one of the addresses used by 
the listener - compare the TNSNAMES.ORA entry with the appropriate LISTENER.ORA file (or  
TNSNAV.ORA if the connection is to go by way of an Interchange). Start the listener on 
the remote machine.`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to deal with TNS, then you can use an [Easy Connect string](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/naming.htm#NETAG255) as the 3rd parameter for `oci_connect()`, also mentioned in the [oci_connect() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php):

```
To use the Easy Connect naming method, PHP must be linked with
Oracle 10g or greater Client libraries.

The Easy Connect string for Oracle 10g is of the form:
[//]host_name[:port][/service_name].

From Oracle 11g, the syntax is:
[//]host_name[:port][/service_name][:server_type][/instance_name]
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
//192.168.1.43:1521/hasdrubal
```